# How to prevent an app from minimizing (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, gui, user-interface

Is there a way, on Windows 7, to prevent a specific application from minimizing to the task bar & the system tray, even if the application itself doesn't support this feature?

Please note: I mean a program that **can** be on window mode, minimized to task-bar or to minimized system tray.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/17413) Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I don't suppose you know any programming languages? Preferably C/C++, VB.Net, or C#. If you do, then you can use various Windows API functions to achieve this.

Comment: To 1: I use an application that sometimes it minimizing itself, and I do not Wish it. For 2: Actually, I know all of the languages above ;)

Comment: Can you name the app, or at least mention the conditions under which it decides to auto-minimise?

Comment: It is set to minimize when another (specific) app has the focus on it.  There is the self-minimizing app and another app that is the **reason** for the condition to happen.